# Extend basic elastic search functionality with language filter (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, filter

I have the following code taken from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#czech-analyzer.

My question is, how can I integrate it to my rails application, so it is used when I search in my models? I already implemented basic elasticsearch functionality (using gems: 'elasticsearch-model' and 'elasticsearch-rails' ) and just need to extend the functionality with this. I am still missing a part where should I put this code and in which form, so it works as it should.

```
    {
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "czech_stop": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwords":  "_czech_" 
        },
        "czech_keywords": {
          "type":       "keyword_marker",
          "keywords":   [] 
        },
        "czech_stemmer": {
          "type":       "stemmer",
          "language":   "czech"
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "czech": {
          "tokenizer":  "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "czech_stop",
            "czech_keywords",
            "czech_stemmer"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for any advices. 
Miroslav

Comment: What gem do you use for ElasticSearch integration?

Comment: I am using these two:

gem 'elasticsearch-model' and 
gem 'elasticsearch-rails'

Comment: @EugZol any idea? Thank you.

Comment: I used this to solve this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33329839/elasticsearch-does-not-seem-to-be-working-as-expected